# Is this a malware creation assistance request?

Tags: discussion, malware

The question I'm concerned about is  [How to encrypt a file in TCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67526165/how-to-encrypt-a-file-in-tcl) . A picture of the question is:

[image]

It looks dodgy, especially with `--no-secmem-warning`, and just triggers a "creepy" feeling in me.

Is that question a malware creation assistance request?

Comment: downvote it, like everything else that you don't like

Comment: Unless there's a crystal-clear case of malicious intent, there's little to be done here, except for a downvote if you feel so inclined. Stack Overflow largely isn't in the business of judging intent, and intentionally doesn't try to be. Related reading: [Dealing with questions of nefarious intent – Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent)

Comment: @zcoop98 If you can vtc this question as a duplicate of that, I'll agree to it.

Comment: you missunderstand me, you downvote the question, as it want to know something that ransomware blackmailer want, per se it is nothing bad about it. as it doesn't tell you why he needs it, but a downvote if the question, is the only things you can do

Comment: @nbk Perhaps I should I have posted on SOCVR instead, but I wanted a wider audience to assess what I might have mis-identified.

Comment: Try running it in a virtual box, if that would work. If it's crystal clear malicious, mod flag it, but other than that  the only thing you can do is downvote.

Comment: some things can be misused but ou take your gut feeling and vote it down, lets see if we get 20 Downvotes

Comment: @nbk You might not have seen [The StackOverflow question that busted the Silk Road guy...](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1nln17/the_stackoverflow_question_that_busted_the_silk/)

Comment: no @AndrewMorton never seen it, but as most malware is oftne written by academics, they wouldn't ask such unsophisticated question

Comment: @nbk One method of filtering out knowledgable people is to use unsophisticated questions, for example with ambiguous constructs. If you would like to know more about that, just send me your email address.

Comment: ...and PIN number... :)

Answer (score 11):

## Vote on clarity.  *Only* close vote if it is off-topic.

Just because a question gives you creepy vibes doesn't mean that it's immediately deserving of being closed.  We wouldn't have any PHP questions open if that were the case!

Remember: [questions about viruses or software that could be used for malicious intent is only off-topic if the *question itself* is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407134/1079354).

Comment: Is `We wouldn't have any PHP questions open if that were the case!` an ad hominem attack?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: [PHP knows what it did and it knows that it deserves it.](http://phpsadness.com) :D

Comment: Is @ericwastl an official representative of PHP?

Comment: Yeah...'We wouldn't have any PHP questions open if that were the case'..is that some kind of problem?